# splash programmin in iphone

Tags: ios

I am new to the iOS development i need to implement splash programming in iphone please give some useful suggestion on it

Comment: I googled splash programming, and didn't see anything that seemed related to iPhone development, could you be more specific?

Comment: "Splash programming", quite a good name for the next Scrum\XP. Now we need a word to replace "Agile" as well.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

if u mean splash screen - you could just replace the Default.png file in your application...